# Add image under text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML & would like to add a image **UNDER** the h1 using CSS.

```
<div class="wf-wrap">
    <div class="page-title-head hgroup">
        <h1>Kookshop</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title-breadcrumbs">...</div>
</div>
```

This is the image I'd like to add: https://www.fs-d.be/wp-content/uploads/knife-300.png

How would you do this? I know we can use the [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) selector in CSS to add text after the header, but I'd really like to add the image **under** the text.

Comment: Under (after text) or behind text (background image)?

Comment: use it as background instead ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution with `:after`, this might help. Setting `display: block` will cause it to appear under the headline.

```css
h1:after {
  content: url('https://www.fs-d.be/wp-content/uploads/knife-300.png');
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wf-wrap">
    <div class="page-title-head hgroup">
        <h1>Kookshop</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title-breadcrumbs">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthias, looking good: https://www.fs-d.be/kookshop/

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `position absolute`, `z-index` and `content: url()`..

```css
.page-title-head.hgroup {
  position: relative;
}
.page-title-head.hgroup::after {
  content: url('https://www.fs-d.be/wp-content/uploads/knife-300.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wf-wrap">
    <div class="page-title-head hgroup">
        <h1>Kookshop</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title-breadcrumbs">...</div>
</div>
```

**fiddle around with it**

- https://jsfiddle.net/2qsdywpk/2/

**further reading**

- [CSS Tricks explains stuff you can do with `content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/)
- [This site has info about z-index and stacking order](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3)

Comment: I just realized that "under the headline" does not necessarily mean "under the headline" while I read your answer :D

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert Ha! And I've just realized the other meaning after reading your comment :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the `background` property in `:after` selector.

Code below.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ykfamw0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.h1 {
  position: relative;
}

.h1:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://www.fs-d.be/wp-content/uploads/knife-300.png);
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wf-wrap">
  <div class="page-title-head hgroup">
    <h1 class="h1">Kookshop</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="page-title-breadcrumbs">...</div>
</div>
```